# Why do radio buttons look ugly in IE8 and IE9 mode

Tags: forms, radio-button, internet-explorer-9

I have some typical radio buttons using the built-in form elements. The radio buttons look fine in Chrome and Firefox 4, but when I use IE9 mode or IE8 mode in IE9 they look very ugly. The radio buttons will look fine in IE9 if I switch IE9 to IE7 compatibility mode. Is there a reason this would happen?

Comment: Are you giving them a size by any chance? I believe certain IE version support sizing them bigger or smaller, but this makes them "ugly".

Comment: Nope. I just checked to make sure. I just gave each radio button a name and value. I did give it a blank id but I doubt that would cause this to happen.

Answer (score 3):

setting width/height (i. e. 13px) helps removing surrounding margins around radio buttons on IE which is quite useful. make sure you don't (re)set border on radios; border:0 renders selected radios with black dot inside and they look 'uglier'

Answer (score 0):

it could be some setting on your computer where you have chosen to highlight performance over appearance.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has changed how it draws thing a lot, read more here: [IE 9 does not use sub-pixel antialiasing under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558773/ie-9-text-renders-very-poorly-is-there-a-workaround/5644887#5644887)