# IE9 Shows certain sections with thinner font

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

We're using Adobe's Source Sans Pro font via Google Web Fonts. The fonts show up fine in every browser we've looked at: Chrome, Firefox, IE7 and IE8, but randomly certain sections show up being rendered thinner in IE9.

The font-weight and size for the sections is the same as the rest of the page: 400 weight, 13px font-size.

The other issues I've looked at discuss full-page solutions, but bizarrely enough, this is only happening in certain sections of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `opacity:.9999;` on your `body` element as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558773/ie-9-does-not-use-sub-pixel-antialiasing-under-certain-conditions)? Also look at the second answer involving the use of `pt` text size measures.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are loading multiple subsets in the same line of code like greek, cyrillic, etc. Try splitting the code in one line for each subset and try it again. This has solved me a lot of trouble in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding the following meta tag solved the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```