# Why does small text look bad on IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

Why does small text look blotchy on IE9?  Below is a screen shot from IE9 and Chrome of the same page:
[image: small text on IE9]
[image: small text on Chrome]

The doctype is:

```
<!doctype html>
 <!-- HTML5  -->
<html xmlns:fb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'>
<head>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558773/ie-9-does-not-use-sub-pixel-antialiasing-under-certain-conditions